# Azure Service Bus SubscriptionExists no Timeout

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus

In my .NET 4.0 WPF app using Azure Service Bus package version 2.8.2 we need to check if a subscription exists, so we usually do that:

```
        var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"));
        namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists("myTopic", $"mySubscription"));
```

When there is Internet connection, everything goes fine. The problem is when this code snippet is called when there is no interent connection.

The SubscriptionExists call blocks the process indefinitely. Even If I use the async version SubscriptionExistsAsync I have the same behavior.

The strange thing is that if the Internet connection is reestablished, I immediately get a TimeoutException (1 minute timeout). But before internet is back, nothing happens.

How can I make this code non blocking while handle no internet scenarios?

I created a small console app to reproduce this problem, based on @Sean Feldman reply. Just run it with no internet connection:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Check().Wait();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task Check()
    {
        var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"));
        var checkTask = namespaceManager.SubscriptionExistsAsync("myTopic", $"mySubscription");
        var delayTask = TaskEx.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        var finishedTask = await TaskEx.WhenAny(checkTask, delayTask).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (finishedTask == delayTask)
            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't get result after 20 seconds");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"Subscription was found: {checkTask.Result}");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my side I cannot repro the issue that you mentioned. If there is no internet, it will throw the exception "The remote name cloud not be resolved" in 1 minute. And As I know the operation timeout is 1 minute. Following is the snapshot of the expection

[image]

I also can catch the expection with fiddler tool

[image]

If it is possible, please have a try use the latest version of [Service Bus SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/).

Comment: I was simulating no internet connection by disabling the network adapter on control panel. Now I tried to simply unplug the cable and then things are different. After 180 seconds I got a UnauthorizedAccessException:The token provider was unable to provide a security token while accessing 'https://blablabla-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/'. Token provider returned message: 'The remote name could not be resolved: 'blablabla-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net''. with a SecurityTokenException and a WebException inner exceptions. Why we have a different exception than your test?

Comment: I believe I cannot use the latest SDK version while targeting net40. Can you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'd get a timeout just like @tom-sun-msft indicated.
I have tried with both, latest and 2.8.2 versions and always the operation timed out. Are you customizing the retry policy or something else?

If you really need to cap it, you could limit the time an operation is executing if the following way:

```
var connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var checkTask = namespaceManager.SubscriptionExistsAsync("myTopic", $"mySubscription");
var delayTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(checkTask, delayTask).ConfigureAwait(false);

if (finishedTask == delayTask)
    Console.WriteLine("Couldn't get result after 20 seconds");
else
    Console.WriteLine($"Subscription was found: {checkTask.Result}");
```

What you do is you let your `checkTask` run along with the delay task for 20 seconds (you can tweak it as to as much as needed) and if the delay task is done first, the check for subscription didn't complete. Otherwise the check is completed and you can get the result.

Comment: Hi @Sean Feldman. I created a console app to reproduce the problem and your approach works fine when there is internet connection. If not, the process gets blocked at SubscriptionExistsAsync call and only after 3 minutos or so I got a System.AggregateException with WebException, SecurityTokenException, UnauthorizedAccessException inner exceptions.

Comment: @IgorKondrasovas I've tested the snippet with and w/o connection and it works. Did update the snippet as it didn't have a valid way of getting the connection string (copied from the original question). The `checkTask` would never complete while `delayTask` would and that would cause the code to continue to the if-block. I suspect something else is going on. Share a repro on GitHub or BitBucket to have a look at it.